# Set to empty value to event.value inside of onChange from outside button

Tags: html, reactjs, dom-events

I have an input element that has a type of file:

```
<input
        id="archiveInput"
        type="file"
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
        ref={ref => (this.uploadArchive = ref)}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        onChange={this.onChangeUploadFile}
      />
```

In the onChange method, I set event.value to ""(empty string) because it is possible to upload the same file again.
So, I also have button that resets all form elements.
How can I set event.value to empty string when I click the button?

Answer (score 0):

You may clear input value using following:

```
event.target.value = null;
```

Also, you can use reference to clear

```
this.uploadArchive.value = "";
```

Comment: Happy to help !!